# How do i open file to be uploaded using php

Tags: php, file

**Context**

I am working on fileupload operations where I want to select and upload any file from any location to my target location. I know the code for reading a simple text file but I want to open and read any randomly selected file.

I have tried several methods but still I am unable to accomplish it. Please
help me. The name for the file is `fileToUpload`. What else shall I use to implement this?

```
 $fileName = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);  // this stores files which i am going to upload
```

For opening this file i am using below code which is:

```
 $handle = fopen($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 'r'); // for opening and reading file but this is giving me below error
```

> Warning: failed to open stream no such file or directory

Comment: You got some html?

Comment: yes , <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

Comment: Please [edit] the question when you have new information, it should all be in your post rather than hidden in the comment. See also [ask] and please review [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as you have a jumble of quoted sections, code sections and text all mixed together. Only use quoting if you're pasting something from another website or quoting another user, or an error messsage. Use code sections for code, and everything else should be text. I'll tidy it for you this time (including your grammar) but please know how to format it next time. Thanks

Comment: Anyway the warning message has nothing to do with the file format, it's simply telling you that the file does not exist at that path. When exactly do you run this code? You should first make sure that a file was actually uploaded, and secondly make sure that you haven't already moved the file to another location on the server.

Comment: You should start by checking whether your upload was actually successful. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Can you post please the `print_r($_FILES);` array, and check if the file exists in `tmp_name` path on the server? Error is saying that file does not exists.